# Resolve missing module error for Yotta with STM32F401

Tags: mbed

I'm trying out development using mbed for the first time (mbed.org) using OS X. I'm using the ST Microelectronics STM32F401 Nucleo board and am trying to follow the "Getting Started" guide. I'm following the instructions in "Your First Application"

http://docs.mbed.com/docs/getting-started-mbed-os/en/latest/FirstProjectmbedOS/

Things seem to go find until the steps for adding dependencies.

I checked the yotta_modules directory to see if the needed modules exists. They don't show as existing.

```
$ yotta install mbed-drivers
info: dependency mbed-drivers is already present in module.json
info: get versions for mbed-hal-st-stm32f401re
info: get versions for cmsis-core-st-stm32f401xe
error: Failed to satisfy dependencies of       /Users/xxx/Documents/blinky/yotta_modules/mbed-hal-st-stm32f4:
error: mbed-hal-st-stm32f401re does not exist in the modules registry. Check that the name is correct, and that it has been published.
error: Failed to satisfy dependencies of /Users/xxx/Documents/blinky/yotta_modules/cmsis-core-stm32f4:
error: cmsis-core-st-stm32f401xe does not exist in the modules registry.    Check that the name is correct, and that it has been published.
```

I took a look at what modules were installed and this is what I get

```
$ ls yotta_modules/
cmsis-core      core-util       mbed-hal-st     minar-platform
cmsis-core-st       dlmalloc        mbed-hal-st-stm32cubef4 ualloc
cmsis-core-stm32f4  mbed-drivers        mbed-hal-st-stm32f4 uvisor-lib
compiler-polyfill   mbed-hal        minar
```

Any idea how I go about getting the missing modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target STM32F401 does not containt all modules published, as you could have noticed that some modules are missing. Because it has not been yet the official supported target (http://www.mbed.com/en/development/hardware/boards/)

There is this pull request adding missing cmsis-core module for it : https://github.com/ARMmbed/cmsis-core-stm32f4/pull/9. To be able to use it, you can clone those repositories which are shared and use yotta link (check the command description here in the yotta docs page). You can locally link that module.

Comment: An update, F401RE modules were updated and should be usable now.